# Automatic translation of messages & conversations in Facebook Messenger, Instant Messaging IM and Chat Apps

Tags: web-apps, chat, iphone-app, facebook, translation

Automatic translation of messages & conversations in Facebook Messenger, Instant Messaging IM and Chat Apps

I have friends from many countries and their command on English and mine over those languages are both "not so perfect".

I'd like to have Auto translation of all conversations in Facebook Messenger  to English and vice versa. 
i.e. in the Message Threads/ Conversations/ Chats.

e.g. I chat with some friends in latin nations in English, and it should auto translate/ send my messages in that persons preferred language, and any messages I receive out to be in my preferred language i.e. English.

I can do Google translate but it means copying every message in and out of FB Messenger and not having a seamless conversation. Also, this copy paste maybe doable on Desktop/ Web but harder on Mobile App.

So, any way for Mobile App, or Web App or Web Browser Extension/ plugin to make this happen?

The only translation thing I found about FB is that it converts latin language STATUS messages on my feed into English: 
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201429652316787

- Sometimes automatic, Sometimes with small click to each, at times not at all
- And FB keeps changing their stuff too often to give a consistent experience

I'd prefer to have some control over this, and preferably do a "Translate all to English SUBTITLES under the original message", with a switchability/ toggling between Always i.e. Automatic and Manual.

Is there a way to enable/ force it or some kind of FB App/ Extension?

Answer (score 0):

So for besides doing the manual copy paste between Google Translate and the messaging app or other cumbersom ways I've found something that goes part of the way.

There are several iPhone/ iOS custom keyboards that one can download from the Apple App Store ( I'm sure Android has some as well, but this is experience so far).

They allow you to type in English in they "active key/ typing area" in pretty much any app and have special Translate buttons that converts any text typed into that area into language of choice, BEFORE you send it out. 
e.g. E > S

I'd have preferred this be semi-automatic where when you click/ tap SEND it translates it to the "set language"  and sends it.

Also the issue is, it wont do the same for incoming messages. I can do a "copy" of the received message in some apps and paste it into "active key/ typing area" and do a translate back. 
e.g. S > E

But I have to manually choose a language each time Sending or Receiving.

I'm sure there will be some limitations due the the underlying Mobile OS, but some of the "steps the user takes" can be improved for overall user experience FLOW.

I'm still evaluating them Custom Keyboard Apps, but will link to some good ones once I figure them out. But this will get the path way open for others looking for this.